# A car working without fuel in the last episode of Fargo S3?

Tags: fargo-tv

In the last episode of Fargo 3rd season, we see Emmit Stussy running out of fuel. But, after the action I won't describe to not spoil anyone, he entered his car and ... it worked again, magically.

My thought is it's a huge scenario mistake. What do you think about it? Did I missed something?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. You should specify. Spoilers are allowed here. And I really do not know what is last episode to you, me or other audience - it changes in time, so edit and let us know the exact episode you are talking about.

Comment: I'm not sure the car stopped for lacking fuel. Maybe a random problem that just needed a reboot.

Comment: It's never stated **why** the car stops but it does seem odd that it just restarts with no issue.

Comment: Also note that the Fargo universe loves *Deus Ex Machina* interventions. Some misterious things happen (UFOs, Gloria's presence detection, Lorne Malvo disapearing in the basement...).

Comment: Despite being closed, I think this is a good question.   As noted, it looked very odd watching the episode.   I had to stop and rewind because the cars looked wrong to me, cause I figured he had to drive away in the truck, but it was still there and Emmit drove away in a car that had given out and stopped mid highway a handful of minutes earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The scene is perhaps misleading: The sound Emmit's car makes sounds a lot like a low fuel warning. But Emmit reacts by moaning "What now?" which is an odd reaction to running out of gas. It's true that Emmit was in an emotional state, and could have missed that he was low on gas to start with, but other car problems could cause the car to start beeping and stop working.

The scene actually played out a bit like a problem I had with my car's cooling system last winter. Leaving the engine off for a while was enough to let it cool down so I could get back to driving—luckily, that was the extent to which my experience mirrored Emmit's.

If we hypothesize that the alarm and malfunction was due to an overheated engine, there's no logical problem to worry about.